# DataTable RowFilter ignore decimals

Tags: .net, vb.net

how do I apply a .RowFilter to my Datatable while ignoring decimal places?

For example, I am currently applying this:

```
Dim FilterView as Integer = 1
DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID = '" & FilterView & "'"
```

This filters my DataTable to show everything with the value = 1 in the ID Column.

But I want to include rows that have 1.1 all the way to 1.9 as well. How do I adjust this filter to include those?

Comment: As explained in the documentation, `RowFilter` understands the syntax of the **[DataColumn.Expression Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Comment: @Plutonix Okay...So...if I'm reading this right the syntax is of a string...? So is the answer "no"?

Comment: Well, the `Expression` property is a string, but thats not the point.  The **[DataView.RowFilter Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** simply directs you there: `See the Expression property of the DataColumn class for more information`  I was trying to save you the redirect time in case you were not inclined to read the Remarks

Comment: Well... this depends. Will your filters always be an integer? Will it always be between `filter` and `filter + 1`?

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly help if you were working with decimals. You expect FilterView to be an integer and ID is a decimal. Not that it changes anything in the answer.

```
Dim FilterView as Decimal = 1
DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "(ID >= '" & FilterView & "') AND (ID >= '" & (FilterView -2) & "')"
```